# Datasheet Parameter for Drive Strength

Tags: drive-strength

I am looking at [a TI level translator](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74avc4t774.pdf) and need a certain current drive strength.  However, in general, what datasheet parameter corresponds to this so I can make sure I provide enough drive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the Output Current, on page 4, and Voh/Vol on page 5.  This part has different drive currents depending on the system voltage.